# sails­postgresql Error while using sails lift command?

Tags: postgresql, sails.js, sails-postgresql

While running $ sails lift command , I am getting this error.

```
info: Starting app...

error: Trying to use unknown adapter, "sails­postgresql", in model `adminintro`.
error: Are you sure that adapter is installed in this Sails app?
error: If you wrote a custom adapter with identity="sails­postgresql", it   should be in this app's adapters directory.
error: Otherwise, if you're trying to use an adapter named `sails­postgresql`, please run `npm install sails-sails­postgresql@0.10.x`
```

Please help me out guys ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the answer ... It was unicode mistake . I have copy n pasted the code for local.js from one of my coworker's pdf file. So when I pasted that code in my local.js "-" was replaced with some unicode http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00AD/index.htm .. and that was causing this issue..